# C# Excel range management

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm dealing with excel files in a C# application.

I'm wondering why this code doesn't work:

```
var value1 = ws.Range[ws.Cells[7,4]].Value;
```

For now I found that this works fine:

```
int i = 7;
var value1 = ws.Range["D" + i.ToString()].Value;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you cant pass to a `Range()` a single `Cells()` Property, you will need to set it with 2 parameters of `Cells()`:

```
var value1 = ws.Range[ws.Cells[7,4],ws.Cells[7,4]].Value;
```

or (use strict the Cells Property):

```
var value1 =  ws.Cells[7,4].Value;
```

Comment: Actually, you can use `Range` property to access a single cell or multiple cells. The second parameter is optional.  Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx

Comment: "A1" is not a Cells Property "A1" in cells is `ws.Range[ws.Cells[1,1],ws.Cells[1,1]]` when you are passing a string you can pass one parameter but the other overload that uses Cells need 2 parameters

Comment: Wrong, the second parameter is **optional**

Comment: so, if i am Wrong prove that you can do that: `ws.Range[ws.Cells[1,1]].Value = "somevalue";`         i say its an overload method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Comment: @S.Dav The documentation is not very precise. The second argument is optional *only* if the first argument is a range name (`"A1"` or `"A1:B2"`). If the first argument is a `Cells` reference, then the second argument is mandatory.

Comment: @InBetween ...and that is why my code doesn't work. Now I understand why my first line of code in the question doesn't work.

Comment: @S.Dav Ok, have it your way. When you get `ws.Range[ws.Cells[7, 4]]` to work correctly, in C# or directly in VBA, come back and enlighten us.

Comment: AFAIK there is no method overloading in Excel API because VBA doesn't support it, so the behavior is based on the parameter types.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of `ws.Range[]` should be in in **A1-style notation**

To access

```
ws.Cells[7,4]
```

you can try this code:

```
var value1 = ws.Range["D7"].Value;
```

And check out [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just a fix for future visitors: 
 `var value1 = ws.Range["D7"].Value;`

Answer (score 1):

try this, I hope this will help you

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
var value1 =(ws.Cells[7, 4] as Excel.Range).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
operator    Example
Range       A1:A1
Union       A1,A1
Intersect   A1 A1
```

Which makes me think that in theory `.Range` should require 2 `Range` parameters as `Application.Union` and `Application.Intersect` do, but fortunately it accepts pretty much any string expression that works in the Excel Address bar. For example:

```
string address = ws.Range["offset(a1,1,2,3,4)"].Address[0, 0]; // "C2:F4"
```

Also, `ws.Cells[7,4]` is `Range` so `.Range(Range)` doesn't make much sense.